# how to recieve confirmation code to register users?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I am applying this tutorial: [Activating User Account via Email](http://www.jonnyreeves.co.uk/2008/06/cakephp-activating-user-account-via-email/)

**When I submit the message, it is sent like this:**

> Hey there ahmed, we will have you up and running in no time, but first we just need you to confirm your user account by clicking the link below:
>
> http://localhost/cakenews/users/activate/24/8877ae4a

**The problem is that I want to create file users/active.ctp to receive activation code when the user clicks on the link. But I dont know what to write on this file to active user**

```
<?php
# /controllers/users_controller.php
# please note that not all code is shown...
uses('sanitize');
class UsersController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Users';
    // Include the Email Component so we can send some out :)
    var $components = array('Email', 'Auth');

    // Allow users to access the following action when not logged in
    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('register', 'confirm', 'logout');
        $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
    }

    // Allows a user to sign up for a new account
    function register() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            // See my previous post if this is forgien to you
 $this->data['User']['password'] = $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['passwrd']);
            $this->User->data = Sanitize::clean($this->data);
            // Successfully created account - send activation email
            if ($this->User->save()) {
                $this->__sendActivationEmail($this->User->getLastInsertID());

                // this view is not show / listed - use your imagination and inform
                // users that an activation email has been sent out to them.
                $this->redirect('/users/register');
            }
            // Failed, clear password field
            else {
                $this->data['User']['passwrd'] = null;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send out an activation email to the user.id specified by $user_id
     *  @param Int $user_id User to send activation email to
     *  @return Boolean indicates success
    */
    function __sendActivationEmail($user_id) {
        $user = $this->User->find(array('User.id' => $user_id), array('User.id','User.email', 'User.username'), null, false);
        if ($user === false) {
            debug(__METHOD__." failed to retrieve User data for user.id: {$user_id}");
            return false;
        }

        // Set data for the "view" of the Email

        $this->set('activate_url', 'http://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . '/cakenews/users/activate/' . $user['User']['id'] . '/' . $this->User->getActivationHash());
  $this->set('username', $this->data['User']['username']);

        $this->Email->to = $user['User']['email'];
        $this->Email->subject = env('SERVER_NAME') . ' - Please confirm your email address';
        $this->Email->from = 'email@gmail.com';
        $this->Email->template = 'user_confirm';
         $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
       $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
           'port'=>'465',
          'timeout'=>'30',
             'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
          'username'=>'email@gmail.com',
             'password'=>'password',
               );
        $this->Email->sendAs = 'text';   // you probably want to use both :)
        return $this->Email->send();
    }
}


/**
 * Activates a user account from an incoming link
 *
 *  @param Int $user_id User.id to activate
 *  @param String $in_hash Incoming Activation Hash from the email
*/
function activate($user_id = null, $in_hash = null) {
    $this->User->id = $user_id;
    if ($this->User->exists() && ($in_hash == $this->User->getActivationHash()))
    {
        // Update the active flag in the database
        $this->User->saveField('active', 1);

        // Let the user know they can now log in!
        $this->Session->setFlash('Your account has been activated, please log in below');
        $this->redirect('login');
    }

    // Activation failed, render '/views/user/activate.ctp' which should tell the user.
}

?>
```

and the model is

```
    /**
     * Creates an activation hash for the current user.
     *
     *  @param Void
     *  @return String activation hash.
    */
   function getActivationHash()
    {
        if (!isset($this->id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return substr(Security::hash(Configure::read('Security.salt') . $this->field('created') . date('Ymd')), 0, 8);
    }
}
?>
```

the views is cakenews\app\views\users\register.ctp

```
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add a article</legend>
<?php
echo $form->create('User');
echo $form->input('username');
echo $form->input('password');
echo $form->input('email');
?>
    </fieldset>
   <?php echo $form->end('Post project');   ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your controller action `activate` is handling the user activation. If user is verified it redirects to login action otherwise it will try to render `activate.ctp` file. So in that case you can just show a message to the user that your registration could not be completed. please try again. To set some data for the view (activate.ctp) you can use controller's set method.

If you don't want to render activate.ctp file at all redirect the user to somewhere else telling registration could not be completed.

Comment: when i click on the link i see this message  Missing Method in UsersController

Error: The action activate is not defined in controller UsersController

Comment: the error is ((( Missing Method in UsersController

Error: The action activate is not defined in controller UsersController

Error: Create UsersController::activate() in file: app\controllers\users_controller. )))